# Download graph using Chartkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails application where the user can answer several questions and get a graph back with the average of all the users' answers.

I managed to display the graph in rails using Chartkick but I am not able to download it.

**my_graph.html.erb**

```
<head>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
</head>
  <%= column_chart @data, adapter: 'google', library: { isStacked: 'percent',  height: 800,}, download: {filename: "boom"}%>
```

**my_graph_controller**

```
@data = [
      {
        name: "Fantasy & Sci Fi", 
        data: [["2010", 10], ["2020", 16], ["2030", 28]]
      },
      {
        name: "Romance", 
        data: [["2010", 24], ["2020", 22], ["2030", 19]]
      },
      {
        name: "Mystery/Crime", 
        data: [["2010", 20], ["2020", 23], ["2030", 29]]
      }
    ]
```

I followed these guides:

https://github.com/ankane/chartkick

https://github.com/ankane/chartkick.js?files=1

But I still do not manage to download the graph, therefore I think I am doing something wrong in the line:

```
 <%= column_chart @data, adapter: 'google', library: { isStacked: 'percent',  height: 800,}, download: {filename: "boom"}%>
```

**OR** the function *download* in not available for the `adapter: 'google'`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to download charts you can use https://github.com/railsjazz/rails_charts/

It supports a column chart and you can download a chart if needed (just customize the toolbar)

Answer (score -1):

Try using gem 'wicked_pdf' which allows you to download pdf files using HTML views.

you simply write an HTML view and add your chart inside this view.

Refer to this https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf for complete documentation on usage of this gem.

Hope this helps!!